# How to debug why Arduino is breaking a while loop?

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I first added an infinite loop. Dugme is a variable for loop. But I couldn't break the loop. That’s why, when I enter the loop, I can’t exit.

```
void otoac()
{
    long duration, distance;
    while(dugme==1)
    { 
        int distanceR = 0;
        int distanceL =  0;
        delay(40);
        if(distance<=24)
        {
            moveStop();
            delay(100);
            moveBackward();
            delay(300);
            moveStop();
            delay(200);
            distanceR = lookRight();
            delay(200);
            distanceL = lookLeft();
            delay(200);
            if(distanceR>=distanceL)
            {
                turnRight();
                moveStop();
            }
            else
            {
                turnLeft();
                moveStop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            moveForward();
        }
        distance = readPing();
    }
}
```

I have an code that when I click on case:'X' it goes in automatic mode (application). I have here the code for when I click out of 'X' that's 'x' (little x) it needs to stop but it doesn't stop. This is the code for the 'x'.

```
void otokapa()
{
    dugme=0
    motor1.setSpeed(0);
    motor2.run(RELEASE); //turn motor1 off
    motor2.setSpeed(0);
    motor2.run(RELEASE); //turn motor2 off
}
```

Someone on YouTube only gave me this answer:

> I added a while loop to the command, as well as a contradiction to the command, meaning, the action that the car will do when the triangle is not pressed, which is nothing.

More code:

```
void loop(){
   if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
    command = Serial.read(); 
    Stop(); 
    switch(command){
    case 'F':  
      forward();
      break;
    case 'B':  
       back();
      break;
    case 'L':  
      left();
      break;
    case 'R':
      right();
      break;
    case 'G':  
      onsol();
      break;
    case 'I':  
      onsag();
      break;
    case 'H':  
      arkasag();
      break;
    case 'J':
      arkasol();
      break;
    case 'W':  
      onac();
      break;
    case 'w':  
      onkapa();
      break;
     case 'X':  
      otoac();
      break;
    case 'x':  
      otokapa();
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

and dugme:

on top of all the code `int dugme=1;` and dugme is only in void otokapa and in otoac `while(dugme==1)`

Comment: C != C++. Tag with the language you're actually using.

Comment: And where do you call the `otokapa` function? Arduino is not running things in parallel, unless you call `otokapa` from `oatac` (directly or indirectly through some other function) then `dugme` will never be set to `0` (unless you do it somewhere else).

Comment: Besides, long-running loops is really not how you should do things on Arduino. The `loop` global function will be called in a loop, you should preferably do *one* thing in it, and let the `loop` function return to be called again.

Comment: @tambre I looked up in google which languages and it said c and c++. So it is only c++? I changed it to c++

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude otokapa function? I just have otokapa as an Void and under case 'x': otokapa(). The same with otoac only case is 'X'. So how do i get the while(dugme==1) in otoac() out of the loop? Do i need to change something in void otoac() or in void otokapa() with dugme=0? My knowledge is very low with this language, i make websites and learning arduino is now an hobby for me for 3 weeks. I appreciate your time and help. So ii didn't understand what you said in your second comment. Can you make an example with my code?

Comment: Are the 2 dugme related?

Comment: But I don't see a `case 'x'`? Perhaps you should show us an [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And remember what I said above about things not happening in parallel!

Comment: Thanks for your time. I added some more code in my post. @Someprogrammerdude
Thanks for your help i appreciate it.

Comment: @Surt I edited and showed in my post where i use dugme. In the top of the code and in void otokapa and void otoac

Answer (score 0):

Is this in essence what your problem looks like?

```
int dugme = 1; // one and only definition of this (ODR)

void otoac() {
    long duration, distance;
    while(dugme==1) { 
    }
}

void otokapa() {
    dugme=0;
} 

void loop(){
   if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
    command = Serial.read(); 
    Stop(); 
    switch(command){
     case 'X':  
      otoac();
      break;
    case 'x':  
      otokapa();
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Possible errors violation of ODR.

if `loop` and `otoac` runs in the same thread you will never get to the serial again.

Comment: Yes, plus the extra code in void otoac and in otokapa. But you know that already ofcourse. How can we solve this? It should be easy to let the code stop when i tap the same button in the application right? Can you come up with something?

Comment: In `loop` you call otoac directly, otoac must run in its own thread then loop is free to check for `'x'` and stop it with `otokapa`.

Comment: In which loop? you mean in the while loop? Can you make an example for me. Because i tried it but i got errors so i am stuck again. I just had like 4 weeks classes about arduino so my knowledge about this is very low. Do you know how to fix it already? Because if you answer me with how you did i will not understand xD

Comment: I mean in `void loop()`.

Comment: oke so i cut the otoac void into the loop? Like under the case'X' or just below the last break;?

Comment: Won't work, either, you have to lookup some asynchronous code, I can't help you more on this sorry.